# WebStorm npm scripts: ng build --prod

Tags: npm, angular-cli, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm wanting to run `ng build --prod` with WebStorm, however it only seems to do `ng build` and misses the `--prod` command.

I'm wanting to run this in WebStorm, not in the terminal.

[image: npm build scripts]

Note: if I add `--prod` to Arguments, it doesn't work:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run build --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto --prod

> cosmoline@0.0.0 build /Users/robertking/go/src/gitlab.com/cosmoline_client
> ng build
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add `--prod` to the build script inside of the *package.json*. For example:

```json
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

Or add an alternate step:

```json
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

If you don't want to do it in the *package.json* file, since WebStorm isn't running *ng* directly (it's running via *npm*), it may not be passing the attributes.
Adding an additional `--` may work (e.g. `-- --prod`).
Or try putting it in quotes (e.g. `"--prod"`).